# Core Data is crashing when adding new Attribute to an existing Entity in a new data model version

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data-migration

I have created a new data model version and set it to current, then I added a new attribute to an existing Entity. After this when I run the code, it is crashing on the `addPersistentStoreWithType` and only I can find from the crash is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x424531f70)`

[image]

The below is the code I am getting the crash.

```
+ (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)coordinator byAddingStoreAtURL:(NSURL *)url configuration:(NSString *)configuration options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError * __autoreleasing*)error {
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    NSError *error1 = nil;
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:EncryptedStoreType configuration:configuration URL:url options:options error:&error1];
    if (error1) {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] Problems to initialize persistent store coordinator: %@, %@", error1, [error1 localizedDescription]);
    }
    
    return coordinator;
}
```

This seems like the crash is occurring on `addPersistentStoreWithType`
[image]

This is the stack at the point it crashed:
[image]

If I delete the newly added attribute, then it runs without any issue with the newly created data model.

Any hints why is it failing? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Could it be the same as this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130416/this-nspersistentstorecoordinator-has-no-persistent-stores-schema-mismatch-or-m

Comment: The question is old, but this recent answer looks like it might possibly solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674642/18248018